# Java Jar hell Runtime Exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch, integration-testing

I am facing the issue with jar hell while running the unit test.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:95)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:99)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$2.run(RandomizedRunner.java:585)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: org.apache.commons.io.CopyUtils
jar1: C:\Users\vvenkatasubbu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-io\commons-io\1.3.2\b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5\commons-io-1.3.2.jar
jar2: C:\Users\vvenkatasubbu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-io\1.3.2\b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5\commons-io-1.3.2.jar
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:282)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:186)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:87)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:93)
    ... 4 more
```

I have got the error like above, resolved those by removing the unnecessary jar file.

But i am facing the issue with the following two jar namely tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar. There is one common class between these two i need both the jar file, can anyone explain me how to resolve the issue. I need both the jar file.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:95)
        at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:99)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$2.run(RandomizedRunner.java:585)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
    class: javax.persistence.PersistenceProperty
    jar1: C:\Users\vvenkatasubbu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.0.36\de87fa65671daad59773c8280eeabbd335f42c\tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar
    jar2: C:\Users\vvenkatasubbu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.javax.persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\5e731d961297e5a07290bfaf3db1fbc8bbbf405a\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:282)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:186)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:87)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:93)
        ... 4 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you need both of them during your tests? what's the name of the class which belongs to both jars?

Comment: I need both while running the application.
not while doing the integration test,

Comment: you're using maven? show your pom.xml? you could make them provided or something like this, to hide from tests

Comment: There are the available dependency,

providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.3.7.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.7.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.7.RELEASE')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed it by overriding the  JarHell class in the unit test sorce folder.

Steps I have done

1. create a separate package in the test folder.

   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap
2. Create a new class and paste the following code.

```java
package org.elasticsearch.bootstrap;

import java.net.URL;

public class JarHell {
    private JarHell() {}
    public static void checkJarHell() throws Exception {}
    public static void checkJarHell(URL urls[]) throws Exception {}
    public static void checkVersionFormat(String targetVersion) {}
    public static void checkJavaVersion(String resource, String targetVersion) {}
    public static URL[] parseClassPath() {return new URL[]{};}
}
```

3. Issue was fixed while doing the gradlew build.
4. To run the integration test separately add the below line to VM arguments in the run configurations.

```sh
    -ea -Dtests.security.manager=false
```

Comment: This looks more like a workaround than a solution, right?

Comment: yes @jbird, Since we are unable to fix the actual problem.