# Jar Hell issue with elasticsearch-test api

Tags: elasticsearch, junit, jar

I am trying to do a mock testing of ES with Junit in my local environment. Simple Junit test on Eclipse IDE works but Maven run doesn't.

I am facing a Jar Hell Runtime issue.

Below are the Maven dependencies that I use.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Below is the Junit class I had written using the Elasticsearch-test api

```
import org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
public class SampleTest extends ESTestCase {
  @Test
  public void runtTest() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("HI Suman");

    setUp();
  }
}
```

I am getting the below exception running it like this

mvn clean install -Dtests.security.manager=false  -Dtests.asserts=false

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:90)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:138)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$2.run(RandomizedRunner.java:585)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\CodeRepo\mock-es\build\resources\test
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:193)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:219)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2662)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:196)
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:88)
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:88)
... 4 more
```

It doesn't show what jars are causing the Jar Hell issue.

I tried to fix with solution provided in 
[Java Jar hell Runtime Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712251/java-jar-hell-runtime-exception)

I created the JarHell class as mentioned. But even that doesn't resolve it.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712251/java-jar-hell-runtime-exception

Comment: @Val As I have mentioned above I tried even with that solution but wasn't able to fix.

Comment: Can you try to run this and see when the two conflicting JARs come from: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.elasticsearch`

Comment: @Val There aren't any conflicts that I see

     [INFO] testES:testES:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.elasticsearch.test:framework:jar:5.0.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:5.0.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    \- org.elasticsearch:securemock:jar:1.2:test

Comment: Where did you put the JarHell class? 
It has to go in the src/test/java in package org.elasticsearch.bootstrap

Comment: It's not actually complaining about a JAR hell, that is just the exception that is being thrown. In fact it is complaining that there are no files in the path at C:\CodeRepo\mock-es\build\resources\test while it expects something to be there.