# Elasticsearch :found jar hell in test classpath

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.6.0

I want to perform unit testing in Elasticsearch for that I am using `Java-test-framework`
I am using `Elasticsearch-1.6.0`
and referring to these link for help 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/using-elasticsearch-test-classes.html
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilderTests.java

here is the code

```
class CampaignESTest extends ESTestCase {

  def getCLient():MockTransportClient={
     val settings = Settings.builder()
                .put(Environment.PATH_HOME_SETTING.getKey(), Files.createTempDir().toString())
                .build();
     val client = new MockTransportClient(settings);  
     client
  }
 }

class CampaignTestSearch extends PlaySpec{
  val client=new CampaignESTest

val response = client.prepareSearch("dbtest")
      .setTypes(CAMPAIGN_COLLECTION_NAME)
      .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
      .addFields("uuid","campaignName","artworkID","activationDate","_source")
      .setQuery(query)
      .execute()
      .actionGet()
  }
```

I am getting these exceptions

```
    Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: org.scalatest.DeferredAbortedSuite *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:138)
[info]   at testcontrollers.campaign.CampaignTestSearch.<init>(CampaignTestSearch.scala:40)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[info]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:468)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:296)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:286)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:90)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:138)
[info]   at testcontrollers.campaign.CampaignTestSearch.<init>(CampaignTestSearch.scala:40)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[info]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:468)
[info]   at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:296)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/testproject/target/web/classes/test
[info]   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
[info]   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
[info]   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
[info]   at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
[info]   at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
[info]   at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
[info]   at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
[info]   at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:219)
[info]   at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
[info]   at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
```

getting an exception on this line

```
val client=new CampaignESTest
```

in class `CampaignTestSearch`

here are the dependencies in `build.sbt` file

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(filters, 
                "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"withSources() withJavadoc(),
                "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.4.0-M3" % "test",
                "com.esotericsoftware.kryo" % "kryo" % "2.10",
                "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.8.0",
                "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.6.4",
                "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.6.0",
                "org.elasticsearch.test" % "framework" % "5.0.0" % "test",
                "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-test-framework" % "4.10.4" % "test",
                "com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting" % "randomizedtesting-runner" % "1.6.0" % "test",
                "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-codecs" % "4.10.4" % "test",
                "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.8.2",
                "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.8.2" ,
                "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.8.2",
                "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6",
                "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.3.6",
                "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.0.9",
                "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.0.0",
                "com.hazelcast" % "hazelcast" % "3.5",
                "com.hazelcast" % "hazelcast-client" % "3.5",
                "com.twitter" % "chill-bijection_2.11" % "0.7.0",
                "com.github.slugify" % "slugify" % "2.1.3" ,
                "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
                "org.codehaus.groovy" % "groovy-all" % "2.4.0",
                "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-expressions" % "4.10.4",
                "com.restfb" % "restfb" % "1.19.0",
                "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.0",
                "org.scribe" % "scribe" % "1.3.5",
                "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.6.2",
                "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client" % "1.20.0",
                "com.google.api.client" % "google-api-client-auth-oauth2" % "1.2.0-alpha",
                "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.20.0",
                "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson" % "1.20.0",
                "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-oauth2" % "v2-rev120-1.20.0",
                "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-appengine" % "1.20.0",
                "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-java6" % "1.20.0",
                "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-jetty" % "1.20.0",
                "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-servlet" % "1.20.0",
                "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-calendar" % "v3-rev120-1.19.1",
                "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
                "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19")
```

How can these exception will be resolved ? also I have tried the solution given here 
[Java Jar hell Runtime Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712251/java-jar-hell-runtime-exception)
Bit when i try to create a class `JarHell` in `org/elasticsearch/bootstarp` package it won't let me create it saying type already exists I also tried searching the Class but did not found ,please guide

Comment: You have a dependency on ES 1.6.0 but you're using the test framework from ES 5 ?

Comment: because there was no dependency available for ES 1.6.0

Comment: Well, those two certainly won't work together for sure.

Comment: so is there any solution for unit testing in ES?

Comment: Well, there is a whole section on testing in the 1.6 documentation. I suggest you go over it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/testing.html

Comment: Why not use a precanned docker image of elastisearch? That would certainly save you from dependency hell.

Comment: In order to avoid those exceptions it seems you should not use PlaySpec to run your tests but instead use the same approach (running tests and code structure) as per your 2-nd link.

Comment: refer https://dzone.com/articles/jar-hell-made-easy

Comment: The JarHell exception is a red herring, this is far more implicating: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/testproject/target/web/classes/test
It looks like you have target files generated in a sub-folder directly from the home directory of user "testproject" which strikes me as suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

As @Val observes, a test framework for ES v5 won't work with ES v1.

Why not upgrade to a newer version of ES?

As I recall, the old v1 has some serious security flaws. Plus ES 5 has better performance, etc.

The other thing you can do is decouple your tests from the exact ES version, by using an http library like [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) or [ESJC](https://github.com/winterstein/elasticsearch-java-client).